# Magento 1.9 Daabase Structure - Product Enabled

Tags: mysql, database, magento, product

I need a report to display what product are enabled on my ERP vs what product is enabled and showing on Magento.

Can someone show me in which database tables I'll be able to see where the product is enabled in Magento, and therefore state with reasonable confidence it is showing on front-end?

Can see in table 'catalog_product_entity' I can match the entity ID to my ERP SKU. But not sure which table it maps the entity_ID to where it is enabled and showing or not?

Answer (score 0):

This is for Magento 1.9.x:

As magento uses eav, and status is integer type, the status is saved in `catalog_product_entity_int` table.

Run this query 
`SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where entity_type_id =4 and attribute_code like '%status%';`

you will find the 'attribute_id' of status is which is 96 in my case.

To find the attribute  product status run this below query

`SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity_int where attribute_id = 96 and entity_id = 76446`

Here 'entity_id' is magento product id and 'attribute_id' is the id of status attribute.

Hope it answers your question.